# Label and NSView in a vibrant background

Tags: swift, macos

I have created a window with a vibrant background (kind of semi-transparent background).

```
override func viewWillAppear() {
super.viewWillAppear()

  let visualEffect = NSVisualEffectView()
  visualEffect.blendingMode = .behindWindow
  visualEffect.state = .active
  visualEffect.material = .light
  view.window?.contentView = visualEffect
}
```

When I add that vibrant background, the text of the label disappears.

How to put a label and an NSView in a vibrant background?

(To test it I have created a new document with a label with no background and that text: label1 and only the code of the vibrant background I give here. When I add the vibrant code, the text of the label disappears)

[image: before]
[image: after]

Comment: can you please show a screen to understand what is happening? What background color do you set for the label?

Comment: I simplify the maximum just to test. I have a label with no background and just text: label 1 in the storyboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// That is what I already had in my question:
let visualEffect = NSVisualEffectView()
visualEffect.blendingMode = NSVisualEffectView.BlendingMode.behindWindow
visualEffect.material = NSVisualEffectView.Material.light

// That is the key to solve the problem:
view.addSubview(visualEffect, positioned: .below, relativeTo: label1) 

// Constraints. They are also necessary:
visualEffect.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
visualEffect.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
visualEffect.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
visualEffect.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
visualEffect.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
```